# PHP: do arrays have a maximum size?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a limit for an array in PHP?

Answer (score 46):

Yes, there's a limit on the maximum number of elements. The hash table structure (arrays are basically wrappers around a hash table) is defined like this (PHP 5.3):

```
typedef struct _hashtable {
    uint nTableSize;
    uint nTableMask;
    uint nNumOfElements;
    ulong nNextFreeElement;
    Bucket *pInternalPointer;   /* Used for element traversal */
    Bucket *pListHead;
    Bucket *pListTail;
    Bucket **arBuckets;
    dtor_func_t pDestructor;
    zend_bool persistent;
    unsigned char nApplyCount;
    zend_bool bApplyProtection;
#if ZEND_DEBUG
    int inconsistent;
#endif
} HashTable;
```

given that

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
```

the limit is the maximum size of an unsigned int (typically 2^32-1 on a 32-bit OS and on most 64-bit OS).

In practice, however, except on machines with lots of RAM and 32-bit ints, you will always hit the memory limit before this becomes an issue.

Comment: You'll probably find you run into serious performance problems populating and dereferencing array elements before you hit the memory limit on most systems.

Comment: @symcbean I doubt it. Lookups and additions take an average constant time. The only thing that can take time is resizing the hash table, but that be avoided if the total number of items can be known in advance.

Comment: @Artefacto, why do you say *most* 64-bit OS has only 2^32-1 for unsigned int?

Comment: @Pacerier Google for "ILP64".

Comment: Since PHP 7.0, a check in range() limits the array size to 2^(32-1)-1.  [via a related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73885850/367456).

Answer (score 8):

The only thing I've come across in reference to php is this from [bytes.com/forum](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/736064-array-maximum-size):

> I don't think there is a limit on how big an array can be, but there is a limit on how much memory your script can use.
>
> The 'memory_limit' directive in the php.ini configuration file holds the max amount of memory your scripts can consume. Try changing this, see if that helps.