# Make Value From Textarea as Array, Loop it and retrieve data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm able using PHP to receive data from user submitted in textarea then split by linebreak then using foreach to process the data. But what happen is when user submit a lots of data, the server will be down and return 504 Gateway. I have learn that using Ajax is possible to submit lots of data and processed one by one in PHP server. I have search around stackoverflow and google but still not having some example to implemented Ajax and PHP for submitting a lots of data.

What I want is user submit data in textarea and the data has to be split with linebreak delimiter and convert it to array with jquery. Then, each value will be submitted with POST method to server through AJAX and the data will be returned one by one.

I have found http://www.imtalk.org/cmps_index.php?pageid=IMT-Website-Submitter, the concept may same like the submitter. Could someone explain how to do that?
I'm still new with jquery and ajax. So, I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a timeout issue to me.

Try increasing `max_execution_time` respectively `max_input_time` in your `php.ini`.

What amounts of input are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6856529/2605859)

Array size is limited only by amount of memory your server has. If your array gets too big, you will get "out of memory" error.