# how many elements could be saved in a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

Just like the title, I want to know how many elements could be saved in a php array.Cause I want to explode a long long sting to an array, and I worry about it will be out of memory. Thanks :)

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856506/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-php

Comment: @dhyanandrasingh That's not just a reference, that's perfect duplicate. It was perfectly fine to flag this question as such with that link :)

Comment: @icecub: i don't have reputation to mark a question duplicate. so till then for help of fuhui huang i mentioned it in reference.

Comment: @dhyanandrasingh Actually you do. Just click `Flag -> A duplicate..` :) That will bring it to the attention of those that can close the question and will add up to your list of Helpfull flags.

Comment: @icecub i checked again and i have only three options 1. spam 2. rude or abusive 3. need moderator intervention. no duplicate flag is available

Comment: @dhyanandrasingh Nah, not on this question because it's already closed as a duplicate. But on other questions you can.

Comment: @icecub thanks i will keep this in mind.

Comment: thanks, i have got the answer from the reference, thank you very much :)