# PHP 7, huge array not loading

Tags: php, arrays

Alright, I use WAMP and I have this massive array. When using PHP 5.6.40, it loads no problem. When using PHP 7.4.0, the page does not load and I get this error: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. Then I reduce my array to a few lines and it loads then. What's the problem? I am very much sure there is no incorrect syntax in my code. Any ideas? Please share

Apache error log:

> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:00.171208 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00428: Parent: child process 12132 exited with status
> 3221225725 -- Restarting.
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:00.296215 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.4.0 configured -- resuming
> normal operations
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:00.296215 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Aug  9 2019 16:46:32
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:00.296215 2020] [core:notice] [pid 10472:tid 416]
> AH00094: Command line:
> 'c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\httpd.exe -d
> C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41'
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:00.298216 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 9976
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:01.231269 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9976:tid
> 332] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:01.831303 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00428: Parent: child process 9976 exited with status 3221225725
> -- Restarting.
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:01.971311 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00455: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.4.0 configured -- resuming
> normal operations
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:01.972311 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS16 Server built: Aug  9 2019 16:46:32
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:01.972311 2020] [core:notice] [pid 10472:tid 416]
> AH00094: Command line:
> 'c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\bin\httpd.exe -d
> C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.41'
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:01.974311 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10472:tid
> 416] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10388
>
> [Sat Jul 11 10:07:02.813359 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10388:tid
> 332] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Comment: Please show us the relevant code. Please read [ask]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856506/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-array-in-php#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20max%20on,ini%20configuration. Here are some help full answers

Comment: You're likely exceeding the PHP memory size limit. Look at your server's error log. Server error logs should not be accessible outside their org.

Comment: Check PHP memory limits for your previous version and current version.

Comment: Doubtfully so. PHP 5.6.40 is happy enough with 128M of space and PHP 7.4.0 is not satisfied having 1024M. Cannot be an issue over here

Comment: Also, show some code please.

Comment: alright, made an edit. added some apache error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are confident that you have allocated enough memory, you can also [try increasing the stack size in the Apache config](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#threadstacksize). For example like so:

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
   ThreadStackSize 6553600
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answer