# What's the behavior of count when array has more than 2147483647 elements?

Tags: php, arrays, php-internals

On a 32-bit system, an array can have as much as 4294967295 elements (as per [Artefacto's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037038/632951) on another thread).

However, [`count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) returns the number of elements as an *int*, and on a 32-bit system, an int is at most 2147483647.

What will `count` return when an array has more than 2147483647 elements?

Comment: And do you have a computer with 200 terabytes of memory?

Comment: Actually, I don't think it can have that many elements on a 32 bit system for lack of address space, even if the size field of the underlying C struct can hold that large a value.

Comment: @mario, that's not the point.

Comment: @mario Besides, how did you arrive at 200 TiB? That would be 51,2 KiB per element, which is a bit excessive for many kinds of records.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, based on the size of an [array element](http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html), you would need at least 163 GiB (32-bit) or 309 GiB (64-bit) of memory before you can observe this behaviour.

The return value of `count()` is based on [`zend_hash_num_elements()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_hash.c#1053):

> `ZEND_API int zend_hash_num_elements(const HashTable *ht)`

This return value then gets cast into a `long` before it's returned to your code; this causes `count()` to return a seemingly negative value. This can be fixed by forcing it back into an unsigned value:

```
$c = count($array_with_pow_2_32_elements);
echo $c; // -2147483648
printf("%u\n", $c); // 2147483648
```

Or:

```
$c = sprintf('%u', $c);
echo $c; // 2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

## This can never happen.

Unless this has changed in recent versions, 2^32 is the maximum number of elements in an array in PHP, even on 64 bit systems.

This is a limitation of the hashtable structure, which uses a uint for     `nTableSize` and `nNumOfElements`: see
[PHP: do arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036957/php-do-arrays-have-a-maximum-size?noredirect=1&lq=1)